# InvalidSelectorException when select element for Python Selenium with xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have this html snippet:

```
<div class="btn">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="S_btn_b" node-type="OK">
        <span>确定</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

And I want to select the `确定` element and click it. I tried the following selector with [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp):

```
confirm_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="btn"]//span[text()="确定"]')
```

But the program just complain that that is not a valid selector with this Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 63, in <module>
    ac.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="btn"]/span[text()="确定"'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 230, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException
```

Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: What happens if you try with only `'//div[@class="btn"]//span'`?

Comment: @MathiasMüller it seems ok when not specify the `text()` of `span` may be the quote sign case the problem?

Comment: No, but it seems those characters (Chinese?) are not supported.

Comment: hmm, but I can use the `find_element_by_link_text(u'确定')` like that, and yes, they are Chinese characters, weird, though.

Comment: @Louis spark idea ! I have tried this `find_element_by_xpath(u'//div[@class="btn"]//span[text()="确定"]')` and it worked. You should answer this problem so that I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not mark your XPath expression as Unicode, the Hanzi will get mangled when the search command is sent to the browser and the search will search for something else than what you want so mark your XPath expression as Unicode:

```
confirm_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u'//div[@class="btn"]//span[text()="确定"]')
```